# Parse XML file uploaded through asp:FileUpload

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml

I have a scenario where a user will upload an XML file, and I'd like to add the file to a table in my database. The hard part, though, is that I need to parse the file and then add some of the information to some different tables.

Every example showing how to get an XML file use a URI to get the file, but how do you get the file straight from either the database or, preferably, from the asp:FileUpload control on postback?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Take a look at the [XmlDocument.Load method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e48zttz7.aspx):

```
XmlDocument myDoc = new XmlDocument();
myDoc.Load(fu_MyFile.FileContent);
```

Answer (score 0):

I did this a while ago with ColdFusion and haven't had to do it yet with Asp.Net, but the basic theme is the same.

1. Save the file in the code behind.
2. Load the file via an Xml trick, XmlDocument like Abe posted or XElement.Load(file)
3. Parse it how you'd like.
4. Delete the file.